# Getting android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element even after adding the android:exported value

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am getting below errors on my Xamarin Forms android project when updating the target version to 33.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#crc6494e14b9856016c30.PNFirebaseIIDService>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. MyProject.Android \obj\Debug\110\AndroidManifest.xml    61

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#crc6494e14b9856016c30.PNFirebaseMessagingService>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.   MyProject.Android \obj\Debug\110\AndroidManifest.xml    66

I have added `android:exported` values on `Manifest` and `MainActivity` files and close the project and did clean and rebuild.

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="2.5" package="com.companyname.appname" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="16">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="appname" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:allowBackup="false" android:icon="@drawable/logo" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="SmartWCM" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.smartwcm.com" android:pathPrefix="/domain" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.smartwcm.com" android:pathPrefix="/domain" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.companyname.appname.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have added exported value on `activity, provider, FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver and FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver`.

**MainActivity**

```
[Service(Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class FirebaseNotificationService : FirebaseMessagingService
{

}

[Service(Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class FirebaseRegistrationService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{

}
```

Added the same on FirebaseRegistrationService and FirebaseNotificationService  under MainActivity.

**But the error shows add it on `PNFirebaseIIDService and PNFirebaseMessagingService`. But these properties are not added on my project.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, the `PNFirebaseIIDService` and `PNFirebaseMessagingService` should be the class in the nuget package you installed about the firebase. So you can try to add the following code in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
```

In addition, you can also try to check the version of the nuget package about firebase you installed. If it's not the newest version, you can update it.

Comment: I have removed the Plugin.FirebasePushNotification from my project and this issue reolved.